# why does plotly go does not show the circular plot properly?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I would like to make a radial/polar chart so that I can show changes of VALUE1 and VALUE2 over time with minute precision. angular labels should be from 0 to 23.

To do so, I implemented the following PLotly code.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# create the dummy data
hour_timetable = [i for i in range(24)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-01 23:59:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 2) for n in range(72)]})
df['HOUR'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour
df['MINUTE'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute
df['VALUE3'] = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=72)
df['VALUE4'] = np.random.uniform(45, 75, size=72)
df['VALUE1'] = np.random.uniform(110, 180, size=72)
df['VALUE2'] = np.random.uniform(90, 130, size=72)
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df = df[(df.ID == 1)]

df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
df['seconds'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.hour * 60 + df['DATE_TIME'].dt.minute

# Compute areas and colors
hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)
df['theta'] = hour_minute[df['seconds']]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
    r=df['VALUE1'],
    theta=df['theta'],
    fill='toself',
    name='VALUE1',
    line=dict(color='red')
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
    r=df['VALUE3'],
    theta=df['theta'],
    fill='toself',
    name='VALUE3',
    line=dict(color='blue')
))

fig.update_layout(
    polar=dict(
        radialaxis=dict(range=[0, 180]),
        angularaxis=dict(
            tickmode='array',
            tickvals=np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 25, endpoint=False),
            ticktext=list(range(25)),
            rotation=-90,
            direction='clockwise'
        )
    ),
    showlegend=True,
    legend=dict(x=1, y=1.1, font=dict(size=8))
)

fig.show()
```

However, I ended up with a chrt that does not show angular labels from 0 to 23, and also VALUE1 and VALUE2 are not well reflected.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using radians whereas the default [`thetaunit`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatterpolar/#scatterpolar-thetaunit) is in degrees. You can either

- set it properly :

  ```py
  fig.update_traces(thetaunit='radians')
  ```
- or use degrees :

  ```py
  # Compute areas and colors
  #hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)
  hour_minute = np.linspace(0, 360, 24 * 60, endpoint=False)
  df['theta'] = hour_minute[df['seconds']]
  ```

Note that the `tickvals` in the angularaxis also expect degrees by default, also because "*angular labels should be from 0 to 23*", you need to fix the linspace range accordingly :

```py
fig.update_layout(
    polar=dict(
        radialaxis=dict(range=[0, 180]),
        angularaxis=dict(
            tickmode='array',
            tickvals=np.linspace(0, 360, 24, endpoint=False),
            ticktext=list(range(24)),
            rotation=-90,
            direction='clockwise'
        )
    ),
    showlegend=True,
    legend=dict(x=1, y=1.1, font=dict(size=8))
)
```

[image]